# Is "is" an auxiliary verb in the sentence "John is working now"?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs, copular-verbs, be

> John is working now.

Is the verb 'is' in this example an auxiliary verb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, as [described in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb#Progressive_aspect)

> The auxiliary verb *be* is used with a
>   present participle to form the
>   progressive aspect; for example, "I am
>   riding my bicycle"

Answer (score 2):

An auxiliary verb is a verb used in forming the tenses, moods, and voices of other verbs.
In English, such verbs are *be*, *do*, and *have*.

Answer (score -1):

Yes 'is' is an auxiliary verb to show the present continuous form of tense in the sentence you have quoted.