# Is "is" an auxiliary verb in the sentence "My mum's bag is blue"?

Tags: parts-of-speech, auxiliary-verbs, copular-verbs, be

> My mum's bag is blue.

Is *is* an auxiliary verb in that sentence? If not, what is it?

---

[Is “is” an auxiliary verb in the sentence “John is working now”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18254/is-is-an-auxiliary-verb)
 was suggested as a possible duplicate, but that post doesn't answer this question because it is about a different kind of sentence ("John is working now" is a progressive/continuous construction, but "My Mum's bag is blue" is not).

Comment: "Is" is an auxiliary verb in sentences like "he is leaving", and "at full moon, she is called by voices from an unknown world".

Answer (score 7):

"Is" is a verb of being, also called a "copula".

> **copula** |ˈkäpyələ|
>   *noun* Logic & Grammar
>   a connecting word, in particular a form of the verb *be* connecting a subject and complement.

Comment: Yep. It's also called a linking verb in some circles, including my old latin class, funnily enough. :)

Comment: In your example sentence, it is also the *main verb* (as opposed to being an *auxiliary verb*).

Comment: @PLL: Hmm, what is the definition of *main verb*? I gather it is not the same as a *finite verb*? Is it any non-auxiliary verb?

Comment: [Towson Education](http://www.towson.edu/ows/verbtypes.htm) distinguishes (I believe wrongly) between 'verbs of being' and 'linking verbs': it muddles semantics and syntax more than is often the case. [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/be) attempts to distinguish the '**existential**' main-verb usage (v.intr.
1. To exist in actuality; have life or reality: I think, therefore I am.) from the **copular**, linking, main-verb usage (Mum's bag is blue / a doozie). Collins places constructions with locative complements (Bill is here) in this category. **Auxiliary** usages are very different.